# reST image grid with captions?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

As an extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219634/image-grid-in-restructuredtext-sphinx): how can you add a description under each of the gridded images using Sphinx and reStructuredText?

For example, a table, three images across with a caption centered under each image.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [How can I place images side-by-side in restructured text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149669/how-can-i-place-images-side-by-side-in-restructured-text).  One answer there suggests `list-table` which I think is much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is possible with just the figure directive, [like it is with the image directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229407/623518). However, whilst horrible to look at, you could wrap the three figures in a table. For example, the following reStructuredText

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| .. figure:: http://placehold.it/150x150 | .. figure:: http://placehold.it/150x150 | .. figure:: http://placehold.it/150x150 |
|   :alt: map to buried treasure          |   :alt: map to buried treasure          |   :alt: map to buried treasure          |
|                                         |                                         |                                         |
|   This is the caption of the figure (a  |   This is the caption of the figure (a  |   This is the caption of the figure (a  |
|   simple paragraph).                    |   simple paragraph).                    |   simple paragraph).                    |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

produces

[image: Table of three figures in a row produced by the above reStructuredText]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was hoping to avoid having to wrap it in a table, but if I have too I will.  I'll probably wait a day or so to see if another answer pops up.  If not I'll accept this one as it is totally valid (but ugly in the source)