# How can I place images side-by-side in restructured text?

Tags: restructuredtext, text-alignment

Is there a way to put 2 different images on the same "line", so, side-by side?

I know there is the `:align:` option, but if I put two images, the first with `:align: left` and the second with `:align: right` it doesn't work, because the latter is put in another paragraph.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try this:

```
.. class:: center

This text is centered
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Can you explain a bit further how this works? That `.. class:: center` goes before both `.. image::`s?

Answer (score 40):

I used [substitution definitions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions):

```
|pic1| any text |pic2|

.. |pic1| image:: img1.png
   :width: 45%

.. |pic2| image:: img2.png
   :width: 45%
```

Comment: The blank newlines in the above answer have to be there. Just tried it without those and it doesn't give the expected output.

Answer (score 15):

```
.. list-table:: 

    * - .. figure:: ../_static/1repren.png

           Fig 1. Representations

      - .. figure:: ../_static/5transparency.png

           Fig 2. Transparency
    * - .. figure:: ../_static/9ele.png

           Fig 3. Electrostatics

      - .. figure:: ../_static/11R3D.PNG.png

           Fig 4. R3D
```

Answer (score 9):

You want the images to be part of the same paragraph and you want them to split the width of the screen so do something like this:

```
.. image:: im1.jpg
    :width: 50 %
.. image:: im2.jpg
    :width: 50 %
```

This doesn't exactly work, there will be some spacing between the 2 images which will put the total width >100%. A simple workaround is setting the widths to 49%. Doing so, below is the output with the unformatted image above to compare:
[RenderedImages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlmjF.jpg)

More reading: [reST docs on Images](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image)

Answer (score 1):

To make this snippet (mentioned above by @fiona) work you need to declare | pic | before referencing it.

```
.. |pic1| image:: img1.png
   :width: 45%

.. |pic2| image:: img2.png
   :width: 45%

|pic1| any text |pic2|
```

Comment: No, you don't need to declare pic1 and pic2 before using them. The other answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The :align: option lets the subsequent content flow around the image.
Using it for two images side-by-side is possible but a bit unintuitive.

Change the order of the images in the source: define the second image first and align it to the right. The following element will flow up to the left of this image (if there is enough space).

```
.. image:: img2.png
   :width: 45%
   :align: right
   
.. image:: img1.png
   :width: 45%
```

A list-table can be used, too

```
.. list-table::
   :width: 100%
   :class: borderless

   * - .. image:: img1.png
          :width: 100%
         
     - .. image:: img2.png
          :width: 100%
```

this can be easily expanded into a "picture grid".