# How to put an image and text side-by-side in a rst file with Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2, restructuredtext

I need to put an image and text side-by-side in a rst document where I also use Jinja2 for text replacement. I tried to solution given [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149669/how-can-i-place-images-side-by-side-in-restructured-text) (see also incorrect(?) documentation [HERE](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions)) but this does not seem to work.

Here is what I have in the rst file:

```
|myimage| {{ name }}
{{ "-" * name|length }}

...

.. |myimage| image:: /_images/myimage.png
   :width: 40%
```

but after rendering it looks like this:

[image]

without showing the image, but literally the text "|myimage|". What is the problem here?

Comment: I think the problem is that there are two different processors, one for Jinja2 and the other for reStructuredText, and they do not "talk" to each other.

Comment: What happens if you try to use an `img` tag?