# side-by-side images in the restructuredtext by sphinx-python

Tags: image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to have the images side by side in pdf and html. I use the sphinx to generate the restructuredtext.

It would be good to look as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu6Z9.png)

I have considered using csv-table, but it does not work well for the outlines around the images are awkward.
.. csv-table::
:header:
:widths: 60, 60

".. figure:: ../_static/1.png
:width: 75mm
:height: 75mm
:align: left", ".. figure:: ../_static/2.png
:width: 75mm
:height: 75mm
:align: right
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2nJr.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22149669/407651

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you fall back to the raw HTML output as this is very difficult, if not impossible to do in Restructed Text only.

```
.. raw:: HTML

   <div style="display: flex">
      <img src="_static/1.png">
      <img src="_static/2.png">
   </div>
```

You are going to need basic HTML skills to style it though.

Comment: Thanks a  lot, but we also need PDF.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using an extension that supports grids, like the following:

- https://github.com/chrisjsewell/sphinx-subfigure
- https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-design

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It is useful for more than 2 figures. But when  I use 2 figures, and installed "myst-parser syntax" as recommended, it does not work. Maybe there is something wrong with my config. Have you tried two figures?

Comment: I haven't used the extension, but there is a two image example at the bottom of the documentation: https://sphinx-subfigure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You could try opening an issue and seeing if they will add the example code used in the examples.

Comment: That is a good idea. Thanks a lot. I have open an issue in https://github.com/chrisjsewell/sphinx-subfigure/issues.