# Subfloat view of images in Sphinx

Tags: image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

my question is simple, but I have not found any really helpful answer until now. I need to display more images in one row. The caption for each of them is optional, but they all should have one group caption as showed below:

[image: Subfloat view in LaTeX]

In LaTeX it is easy to do, but requires extra packages. I am really wondering, it is easy to do in Sphinx/reSt either?

Edit: I need to have caption centered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reST image grid with captions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148428/rest-image-grid-with-captions)

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with group caption, simply try this:

```
.. image:: gull.png
    :width: 30 %

.. image:: tiger.png
    :width: 30 %

.. image:: mouse.png
    :width: 30 %

.. centered:: Group caption
```

Comment: Well, it is is not my case. I tried it and, of course, it works, but in any other places I use figure directive with :align: center attribute. I would like to see "Group caption" in your example that is centered...